# storing a file to a symlink in laravel 9

Tags: laravel, storage

I'm trying to get an image from the web and store it locally in my 'app/library' folder using Laravel 9. After battling for an hour with get_file_contents, I finally discovered guzzler and the file is fetched properly. Now I'm trying to save it using the following command.

```
$stored = Storage::put(storage_path('app/library').'/'.$filename, $content)'
```

$stored shows as '1', which leads me to think that it's worked, but the file is not in my app/library folder. Nor can I find any file with the correct name anywhere in my project.

Is there something wrong with my command?

Comment: `app/library` isn't the same as `storage/app/library`

Comment: good point, but the storage path for 'app/library' is storage/app/library, right? 'storage' appears in the path when I print it out.

Comment: if you are using the local "disk" as the default it already points to `storage_path('app')` as the root so you don't pass a full path to the call to `put`, just a path from the root of the storage disk (relative to the root)

Comment: That seems to have been it. $stored = Storage::put('library/'.$filename, $content)' worked. Thanks. Do you want to create the answer so I can accept it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to lagbox for the answer. I was overthinking it and didn't need 'storage_path()'. The following worked.

```
$stored = Storage::put('library/'.$filename, $content)'
```

Answer (score 0):

Run the `storage:link` command.

See https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/filesystem#the-public-disk

Comment: yes, the symlink is working, but I don't think that's required for storing the file - only for making it public.